# How does a server communicate with a client who request service of 2 processes?

Tags: sockets, port

I am trying to understand how do the sockets, ports, clients and servers works. Assume there is a client which tries to connect to the same server which has two processes. How does the client can access the 2 processes of the server at the same time?

Please mention any good reference link if you know.

Thank you.

Comment: The server communicates iwth the client via the socket it accepted when the client connected. If the client connects twice, the server has two sockets for it.

Answer (score -1):

I already had to do a homework in the socket. In a nutshell what I understood for my part is that the socket is the end of tunnel between two devices. The customer taken a free port will occupy by a socket and server doing same thing. When the link is established, there can be exchanges of various kinds between the two devices. These are the basics of what I learned about sockets.
Here is a little lesson that confirms my words : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Sorry but that's an F. A socket is an *endpoint* of a connection. Not the connction ('tunnell') itself.

Comment: Ok i will edit my answer and I will go and read again.. thanks.

Comment: I reread and I understood better. The address plus the port forms the point of entry of the communication. And the communication will land on the socket that forms the end point.